# Isn't "birthed" wrong?

Tags: grammar

As far as I know it is wrong to say "birthed", isn't it?

I am asking since I read it in a post on a blog I follow.

The post: www.brainpickings.org/index.php/2014/03/12/austin-kleon-show-your-work/

The phrase: "ideas are often birthed by a group of creative individuals"

As an English foreign language speaker I was taught that we say" born" and I recall "birthed" is grammatically wrong.

Is the word correct or is new in the Internet age?

Comment: Why do you think it is wrong? Can you please say where you found it? In what context?

Comment: @user10853 Well, it's a real word, so it depends on how its used.

Comment: Context is always helpful. If you're referring to a ship, then it's wrong. If you're *talking* about a ship, then no one will notice. What are you referring to?

Comment: This is General Reference. Any reasonable dictionary will define the *verb* [***birth***](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/birth) as *to give birth to*.

Comment: @Jim: Pity the poor woman trying to *birth* a ship! But she could certainly ***berth*** it.

Comment: This question lacks context. It can be right or wrong to say "birthed" depending on the context. No way to know the way this question is posed.

Comment: Question updated

Comment: The verb "birth" existed well before the idea of the internet was birthed in the 1960s.

Comment: So birthed, born, & give(n) birth are equivalent?

Comment: @user10853: Obviously they're not "equivalent", in that *birthed = born* is vanishingly rare (as you must have known in order to ask the question in the first place). But it is ***valid English***.

Comment: Three people are involved - the one born, she who gives birth, and they who assist.

**For the one born.**

My sister is named Elizabeth as she was born on Coronation Day. Born on D-Day they named him Montgomery. 

**For the one giving birth**

Mary bore a son, called Jesus (dated). Jane gave birth to a bonny bouncing boy.     

**For those assisting**

We encourage all mothers to have a birthing partner. Helen Sims, a midwife from Kent, has received an award for having birthed 1,000 babies. 'Breach-birthing' is rarely done these days. Home-birthing is an option which some mothers prefer.

Comment: If *birther* is a word then *birthed* seems plausible.  Indeed my spell-checker prefers the latter.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The verb *birth* exists and can be found in the OED as a transitive verb meaning "To give birth to; to give rise to"

> 1945 in Amer. Speech (1946) XXI. 303 The plan for UNO was birthed at Dumbarton Oaks.

It is in the Longman Dictionary of the English Language "to bring forth as a mother. To cause the development or creation of"

On line dictionaries have it as well:
[Merriam Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/birth)
[Free Dictionary](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/birth)

Found on the web :

- [The Guardian](http://www.theguardian.com/commentisfree/2014/mar/12/conservative-poverty-plan-birth-control-food-stamps) (British)

  > The right's poverty plan: shame poor kids and the vaginas that birthed them
- [The Washington Post](http://www.washingtonpost.com/blogs/the-switch/wp/2013/12/19/this-100-year-old-deal-birthed-the-modern-phone-system-and-its-all-about-to-end/) (US)

  > This 100-year-old deal birthed the modern phone system
- [In a contemporary essay](http://books.google.fr/books?id=-oxMWrooH7UC&pg=PA154&lpg=PA154&dq=%22she%20birthed%20him%20%22&source=bl&ots=lx6hJuvseA&sig=XdTw3hODWNr8CQYQKx37474Y-_s&hl=fr&sa=X&ei=VoosU9-VEOTx0gWHrYCoBw&ved=0CFkQ6AEwBw#v=onepage&q=%22she%20birthed%20him%20%22&f=false) by Andrea Raynor:

  > She birthed him and knew him and counted his toes and brushed her lips on his baby head.

Edit after OP completed their answer :
Birth (birthed, birthed) and bear (bore, born(e)) are two different verbs.

**Bear** means "carry".
**Birth** (as a verb) means  "give birth".

The following three mean the same thing:
 She bore two boys.  / She brought two boys into the world. / She birthed two boys.
The first two are more common but the third one is quite correct and you will find lots of examples if you do a little research on the internet.

And when used for an idea and not for a person, as in your example,  then the use of "birth" is quite frequent.

Comment: Personally I would not use 'birth' in the sense of 'giving birth to' even though the Guardian has been known to. But I might use it in the context of midwifery. See the interesting answer from Josh61.

Comment: It's considerably older than that. Working backwards from Prissy in "Gone With the Wind" (1939: *I don't know nothin bout birthin no babies*), Google Books offers examples for every decade until the 1850s.

Answer (score 3):

I found this, hope it can help.

tr.v. birthed, birth·ing, births Chiefly Southern U.S.
1. To deliver (a baby).
2. To bear (a child).

Until recently the use of birth as a verb meaning "to bear (a child)" has been confined to Southern speech: "Heap o' good it do a woman to birth a mess o' young uns and raise 'em and then have 'em all go off to oncet" (Marjorie K. Rawlings). Recently, however, the nonstandard Southern usage has coincided with widespread usage of verbs derived from nouns, such as parent, network, and microwave. Birth in this new usage is most commonly found in its present participial form and is used as an adjective in compounds such as birthing center.

Answer (score 0):

**Birthed** is a word, the past tense and past participle of *birth*.

[Here's](http://www.anthro.utah.edu/PDFs/PNAS-2011-DeSilva-1003865108.pdf) a source a bit more credible than a blog using it.

Source: OED.

Comment: That _is_ a blog. A well-written blog, but a blog just the same. It even has "blogs" in the URL!

Comment: @CurtisH it's the blog with segments borrowed from a paper in a ecology/biology journal. I'll cite the actual publication information.